# Another or/nor usage question

Tags: word-usage

Both sound OK, but the phrase with nor seems more emphatic.  Are both correct?

"An examination that was performed greater than 30 days prior to patient services cannot
be utilized **nor** updated."

vs.

"An examination that was performed greater than 30 days prior to patient services cannot
be utilized **or** updated."

Comment: In contemporary English (AmE, anyway), the only place "*nor*" is still used is in combination with "*neither*", and even that's fading. In other words, going with "*or*" is always a safe bet.

Comment: You have two choices: 1) ...can ***neither*** be utilized ***nor*** updated. 20 ...can***not*** be utilized ***or** updated

Comment: Actually, there are other choices. Another use for _nor_ is to emphasize and reiterate prohibitions. "... _cannot be utilized. Nor can it be updated._"

Comment: Bigger boxes tend to be more comfortable living spaces. Am I correct in noticing that to use *nor*  in *emphasizing or reiterating this prohibition*, we ***must*** add another *can*  to the OP sentence (without the not)?

Answer (score 1):

In this case Example 2 would be your best option. As mentioned above, "nor" should usually only be used with "neither". Despite this, I am inclined to say that the following is acceptable:

> An examination that was performed greater than 30 days prior to patient services cannot be utilised **nor can it be** updated.

In the above example, "nor" negates the phrase *can it be*, thus having the simple meaning *and it also cannot be*.

Comment: I agree with the conclusions here that option 2 sounds better than option 1, and that option 1 works better if "nor updated" is extended to say "nor can it be updated." But I also think that the author of the original example would do well to jettison the clunky wording "An examination that was performed greater than ..." in favor of "An examination performed more than ..."